# Magento 2 How Payment and Shipping Works!

Tags: payment-methods, shipping-methods, ups, dhl, braintree

I have some doubts about how this works can someone who has experience with any, preferably **Braintree** payment method and **DHL** or **UPS** Shipping Methods.

1- When Payment is send to Braintree and is success does Braintree update the order `status` in Magento?

2- DHL or UPS Shipping, when and order is created does the order get send to DHL or UPS to process at the time of purchase, and do they also update the order `status` in Magento?

Comment: @Bare Feet  Any experience on this ?

Comment: @Jai Any experience on this ?

Comment: @Manoj Deswal Any experience on this ?